# Haskell confusion with ContT, callCC, when 

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

Continuing quest to make sense of ContT and friends. Please consider the (absurd but illustrative) code below:

```
v :: IO (Either String [String])
v = return $ Left "Error message"

doit :: IO (Either String ())
doit = (flip runContT return) $ callCC $ \k -> do
    x <- liftIO $ v
    x2 <- either (k . Left) return x
    when True $ k (Left "Error message 2")
    -- k (Left "Error message 3")
    return $ Right () -- success
```

This code does not compile. However, if the replace the `when` with the commented k call below it, it compiles. What's going on?

Alternatively, if I comment out the x2 line, it also compiles. ???

Obviously, this is a distilled version of the original code and so all of the elements serve a purpose. Appreciate explanatory help on what's going on and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: "Continuing quest to make sense of ContT and friends"? A fool's errand! The Continuation that can be understood is not the true Continuation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here has to do with the types of `when` and `either`, not anything particular to ContT:

```
when :: forall (m :: * -> *). (Monad m) => Bool -> m () -> m ()
either :: forall a c b. (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
```

The second argument needs to be of type `m ()` for some monad `m`. The `when` line of your code could thus be amended like so:

```
when True $ k (Left "Error message 2") >> return ()
```

to make the code compile. This is probably not what you want to do, but it gives us a hint as to what might be wrong: `k`'s type has been inferred to be something unpalatable to `when`.

Now for the `either` signature: notice that the two arguments to `either` must be functions which produce results of the same type. The type of `return` here is determined by the type of `x`, which is in turn fixed by the explicit signature on `v`. Thus the `(k . Left)` bit must have the same type; this in turn fixes the type of `k` at (GHC-determined)

```
k :: Either String () -> ContT (Either String ()) IO [String]
```

This is incompatible with `when`'s expectations.

When you comment out the `x2` line, however, its effect on the type checker's view of the code is removed, so `k` is no longer forced into an inconvenient type and is free to assume the type

```
k :: Either [Char] () -> ContT (Either [Char] ()) IO ()
```

which is fine in `when`'s book. Thus, the code compiles.

As a final note, I used GHCi's breakpoints facility to obtain the exact types of `k` under the two scenarios -- I'm nowhere near expert enough to write them out by hand and be in any way assured of their correctness. :-) Use `:break ModuleName line-number column-number` to try it out.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense but doesn't quite solve my problem. I think the intent of my code is clear. Looking for a way to get some data from IO, and on various conditions, escape out of the function. What would be the proper way to write this with continuations?

Comment: Well, actually you can use the trick I mentioned in the answer and use `k (...) >> return ()` in the `when` bit (and similar expressions wherever type mismatches arise), because the `>> return ()` part doesn't matter -- if `k` gets called at this point, you're out of this computation anyway. I've suggested in the answer that this is probably not what you want, but now I believe that the very opposite is true. Could you give it a try and let me know if it helps? If it does, I'll edit it in the answer proper.

Comment: Of course your code as it stands now is guaranteed to return `Left "Error message"` whichever small fix you apply to make it compile, because `k` gets called already on the `either` line. If you change `v` to `return $ Right ["Foo"]` and add `>> return ()` to the `when` line, then it'll return `Left "Error message 2"`. HTH.